# I need return value from dapper execute insert

Tags: c#, dapper

BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK is populated from a database trigger when the row is inserted. I need to retrieve this value as part of my insert. How would I go about doing that? I have tried this in order to get it as an output parameter, but it is doesn't return the value.

```
   public BKG_AOR_CHANGE BKG_AOR_CHANGE_Create(BKG_AOR_CHANGE dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

            parameters.Add(name: "MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT", value: dto.MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "MEMBER_ID", value: dto.MEMBER_ID, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "MEMBER_NAME", value: dto.MEMBER_NAME, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CUSTOMER_TYPE", value: dto.CUSTOMER_TYPE, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CURR_AGENT_ID", value: dto.CURR_AGENT_ID, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CURR_AGENT_NAME", value: dto.CURR_AGENT_NAME, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CURR_AGENCY_ID", value: dto.CURR_AGENCY_ID, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK", direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 31);

            var sql = @"INSERT
                            INTO DS_BROKERAGE.BKG_AOR_CHANGE
                              (
                                MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT,
                                MEMBER_ID,
                                MEMBER_NAME,
                                CUSTOMER_TYPE,
                                CURR_AGENT_ID,
                                CURR_AGENT_NAME,
                                CURR_AGENCY_ID,
                              )
                              VALUES
                              (
                                :MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT,
                                :MEMBER_ID,
                                :MEMBER_NAME,
                                :CUSTOMER_TYPE,
                                :CURR_AGENT_ID,
                                :CURR_AGENT_NAME,
                                :CURR_AGENCY_ID,
                              )";
            this._db.Execute(sql, parameters);

            dto.BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK = parameters.Get<int>("BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK");

            return dto;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, looks like I was just missing the returning statement

```
    public BKG_AOR_CHANGE BKG_AOR_CHANGE_Create(BKG_AOR_CHANGE dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

            parameters.Add(name: "MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT", value: dto.MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "MEMBER_ID", value: dto.MEMBER_ID, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "MEMBER_NAME", value: dto.MEMBER_NAME, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CUSTOMER_TYPE", value: dto.CUSTOMER_TYPE, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CURR_AGENT_ID", value: dto.CURR_AGENT_ID, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CURR_AGENT_NAME", value: dto.CURR_AGENT_NAME, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "CURR_AGENCY_ID", value: dto.CURR_AGENCY_ID, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add(name: "BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK", direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 31);

            var sql = @"INSERT
                            INTO DS_BROKERAGE.BKG_AOR_CHANGE
                              (
                                MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT,
                                MEMBER_ID,
                                MEMBER_NAME,
                                CUSTOMER_TYPE,
                                CURR_AGENT_ID,
                                CURR_AGENT_NAME,
                                CURR_AGENCY_ID,
                              )
                              VALUES
                              (
                                :MEMBER_ORIG_EFF_DT,
                                :MEMBER_ID,
                                :MEMBER_NAME,
                                :CUSTOMER_TYPE,
                                :CURR_AGENT_ID,
                                :CURR_AGENT_NAME,
                                :CURR_AGENCY_ID,
                              )
                              RETURNING BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK INTO :BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK";

            this._db.Execute(sql, parameters);

            dto.BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK = parameters.Get<int>("BKG_AOR_CHANGE_SK");

            return dto;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```